# Measure RANKX over entire period, and not for each axis

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having trouble understanding why my Rankx measure is only evaluating the rank for each axis point on a diagram, and not for the entire series.

[image]

Above Diagram has a filter with the DAX function shown in the picture. It's set to `is less than or equal to` 1. Cosmo is Rank 1 for the entire period, and I'd like my diagram only to show him, below picture shows where I'd like to get to.

[image]

This should of course also play if the Rank filter is set to 2, 3...n.

Below is an image of my relationships

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would add an ALL function to your CALCULATE function's Filter clause, to expand it's scope to all Months, e.g.

```
Rank = RANKX( ALL ( Tabel2[Name] ) , CALCULATE( Tabel3[ValueSum] , ALL( Tabel1 ) ) )
```

As you had it, it was calculating a new Rank for each month.